# Use trigger to determine to implement insert or not

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a beginner of SQL and Oracle database, and I need a little help about trigger. Here is the question:

I need to create a trigger that before insert a row into table Room, it will check this new row's hotel_id to see if it exists in another table Hotel. If the new hotel_id exists, then do the insert; if not, cancel this insert.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON ROOM 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  if (:new.hotel_id in (select hotel_id from hotel)) then
    --execute the insert;
    else
      --cancel the insert;
  end if;
END;
```

I'm not sure that SQL has syntax that can be used to continue or cancel an operation. If there is, please teach me or attach the link related to it.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I'm using oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way of doing this is using foreign key constraints.

You can define/alter your room table to refer it in the hotel_id column.

`CREATE TABLE`:

```
create table room (
    . . .,
    hotel_id int not null,
    constraint fk_hotel_id foreign key (hotel_id)
        references hotel(hotel_id)
);
```

`ALTER TABLE`:

```
alter table room
add constraint fk_hotel_id foreign key (hotel_id)
    references hotel(hotel_id);
```

If the two table exists in different databases, then you can use trigger.

You can use `raise_application_error` proc to abort the execution and throw error.

```
create or replace trigger trigger1 
before insert or update
on room for each row
declare
    n integer := 0;
begin
    select count(*) into n
    from hotel
    where hotel_id = :new.hotel_id;

    if n = 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Hotel ID doesn't exist');
    end if;

end;
```

Comment: But Room table and Hotel table are located in two different database, it always gives me an error when I create foreign key constraints. So I think using trigger may achieve the goal.

Comment: WOW. I never thought of using count() function into this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As GurV said, foreign keys are more appropriate way for doing this

Though, here is trigger way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON ROOM 
FOR EACH ROW 
declare myvar INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO myvar FROM Hotel WHERE hotel_id = :NEW.hotel_id FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
    exception 
    when no_data_found then
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'some_error_message');
END;
```

Comment: This works only when the hotel_id's names are unique

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, can you tell more clearly, when this not works ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Oto. I'm trying to understand and implement this code.